# ERROR: Could not build wheels for pyopencl which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly

Tags: python, pyopencl

I am trying to install pyopencl using `pip install pyopencl` but am getting the following error lines:

```
ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyopencl \
Failed to build pyopencl \
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pyopencl which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly \
```

I've seen other posts about errors like this but those solutions did not seem to work.

Full error log trace:

[image]

Comment: Some questions: Did you run the program as root? Do you have Visual Basic installed (..correctly)?

Comment: Sorry, I am a little new to this, but I am not sure what you mean by running the program as root. And I do have Visual Basic installed, which I downloaded from https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/ (I hope this is correct. I have the newest version of visual studio and also downloaded "Build tools for visual studios" from the above link).

Comment: Im sorry, I forgot that you are using Windows (running as "root" means as administrator, so with "sudo" in front of it); I sometimes have this problem too on my Windows computer, but I dont know what you can do. Maybe search for "pip failed to build" or sth